# Pyforms AttributeError: ‘module’ object has no attribute ‘start_app’

Tags: python, pyforms

After installing pyforms on my Raspberry Pi 3 i tried running the example i found on [readthedocs](http://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/getting-started/the-basic/#the-basic), but the application is throwing an `AttributeError` (I tried both python2 and python3)

---

**Python Code**

```
import pyforms
from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlButton

class SimpleExample1(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleExample1,self).__init__('Simple example 1')

        #Definition of the forms fields
        self._firstname     = ControlText('First name', 'Default value')
        self._middlename    = ControlText('Middle name')
        self._lastname      = ControlText('Lastname name')
        self._fullname      = ControlText('Full name')
        self._button        = ControlButton('Press this button')


#Execute the application
if __name__ == "__main__":   pyforms.start_app( SimpleExample1 )
```

---

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PiControl.py", line 20, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":   pyforms.start_app( SimpleExample1 )
AttributeError: ‘module’ object has no attribute ‘start_app’
```

---

---

**Edit:**

I tried to import `start_app` manually with

```
from pyforms.gui.standaloneManager import start_app
```

but then I get another `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PiControl.py", line 4, in <module>
    from   pyforms.gui.standaloneManager import start_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'start_app'
```

Comment: do you have any other file named pyforms in the same directory?

Comment: @AbhishekP no, PiControl.py is the only file in the directory

Comment: @Error404, if you import start_app manually, can you start an app? `from pyforms.gui.standaloneManager import start_app`. Check your `PYFORMS_MODE` environment variable: right before `start_app` do: `import os; print(os.environ.get('PYFORMS_MODE'))`

Comment: @9dogs the `PYFORMS_MODE` environment variable was unset, so i tried setting it to `GUI`, which produces the same result

Comment: @9dogs importing `start_app` from `pyforms.gui.standaloneManager` produced an `ImportError` (see updated question)

Comment: @Error404 This is strange... Do you have `git` available? Try installing latest versions from repo: `pip install git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms.git --upgrade` 
`pip install git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings.git --upgrade`, `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/fchampalimaud/logging-bootstrap.git`

Comment: @9dogs 
 
That fixed the problem. Thanks! If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very strange behavior and possibly means that your installation is broken. Try to install the latest versions from a repo:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms.git 
pip install -U git+https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings.git
pip install -U git+https://bitbucket.org/fchampalimaud/logging-bootstrap.git
```